# reidirect() in react router not redirecting

Tags: redirect

```
export async function action({ request }){
  
  const formData = await request.formData()  
  const email = formData.get('email');
  const password  = formData.get('password');
  const logData = await loginUser({email, password})  
  console.log(logData)
  localStorage.setItem('loggedin', true)
  return redirect("/host")
  
}

but everything work succesfully my app is not redirecting and its not showing any error
```

i have try checking documentation and id id not see anything wrong